How to find all views/stored procedures in a database that reference other servers
For cases where organizations move to enforcing TLS encryption on connections to SQL Server instances, groups may need to look through all views/stored procedures (among other things) to find references to other servers, and update the reference to the FQDN. Is there any way to find all views/stored procedures that reference other servers?
There are several ways to find views/stored procedures that reference specific views/stored procedures, using various sys tables (sys.procedures / sys.sql_modules), but not finding anything for this.
My only idea was to try and look at sys.sql_modules.definition to find any "3 dot" references, but I'm not sure if there's a safe way to do so that avoids false positives (we could try and look for instances of 3 periods in a single field but it is theoretically possible to have periods in table/column names thus catching false positives).
Thanks in advance :)

Check out sys.sql_expression_dependencies.

@DanGuzman oooh....if I'm reading that definition correctly:
select * from sys.sql_expression_dependencies deps where deps.referenced_server_name is not null
Gets me that exactly? Thank you!

Just watch out for dynamic sql which is common when dealing with linked servers. They won't turn up probably
